# vb.net getting value from a new name sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
 Dim cd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select datepart(mm,Birthday) as MonthDates from Information where Name='" & cbname.Text & "'", con)
            Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = cd.ExecuteReader
            While reader1.Read
                Dim mon As Integer = reader1("MonthDates")
                lblbday.Text = mon
```

I used this code to assume that the new named column in SQL will be read in vb net but its not reading the new named Column "MonthDates".

What is wrong with the code? Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: btw, connection is already in. i just ask for the code for reading the new named column in query. thank you!

Comment: Are you getting some exception? Put a breakpoint on the `While` line and see if `reader1` has opened successfully and what's the value of `reader1["MonthDates"]` at that point.

Comment: thank you @dotNET . i just put exception so i knew the problem.. the only problem is i need to close the other open Reader :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should dispose connection after query (in my example USING do this):

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(....)
    Dim cd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select datepart(mm,Birthday) as MonthDates from Information where Name='" & cbname.Text & "'", con)
    Dim mon As Integer = cd.ExecuteScalar()
    lblbday.Text = mon
End Using
```